# Is a request for text support for doctrine a doctrinal question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

This is a "could I ask this question"-question.

Having a bit of holiday over Christmas and New Year I'm going over some notes I've made of topics I want to look at.

One such question regards the use of terminology such as "Jesus took our illnesses upon himself on the cross".

I've read a little and seen that there's a variety of perspectives that this statement could cover, but I'd be interested to see if anyone could give me the background texts to support such a statement (one would not have to agree with the exegesis to present the texts used to support the doctrine).

I see a good answer being then "Those that believe X would support it using these texts, or refer to this work for their argument".

This could lead to follow up questions on interesting or controversial aspects of these texts... but is this question too "doctrinal"? And does that render it inappropriate?
If so, where would it belong?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, any question like that would be off-topic here IMO - it might fit on C.SE?

Comment: This is where we end up re-hashing other questions about what we want here, perhaps. 
I have to say that I feel uncomfortable with the general "chaos" that I perceive over at C.SE, so I haven't even created a login. Perhaps I shall do so and ask this question to see what one gets there...

Answer (score 1):

In reference to Jacks [suggestion](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/36) that this might fit on C.SE, I could see this going a couple ways depending on what you had in mind.

- If you would like to know how different Christian traditions interpret that and perhaps what doctrines they build off of it, C.SE would be the place to ask.
- If you want somebody to make judgement calls on a "right" interpretation or whether the assorted doctrines are right or wrong, we steer clear of that on C.SE.
- If you want to know what other texts get pulled to cover the issue, I could see it going either way. If you wanted ones that were textually related, it might work on either site but I would tend to prefer BH.SE. If you want to know what issues are related doctrinal and how those other issues get built, C.SE would be the place.

I hope this gives you a few ideas. Do we have some chaos over at C.SE? Sure we do. But we're not in a state of anarchy yet.